# What is a "valid" coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate, definition

I was reading ["Natural Coordinate System in Curved Spacetime" by Ying-Qui Gu](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0612176).  The first sentence of the abstract struck me (bold emphasis added by me):

> In this paper we establish a generally and globally **valid coordinate
> system** in curved space-time with the simultaneous hypersurface
> orthogonal to the time coordinate.

Is there a generally accepted set of criteria to determine if a coordinate system is valid?  Are some coordinate systems invalid?

Comment: The "valid" should be read together with "globally". It's a coordinate system that is *globally valid*, in contrast to one that is only *locally valid*. But I think this question belong at physics.SE

Answer (score 1):

Some desirable properties are that the coordinates of events are uniquely specified; that the coordinate system doesn't lead to singularities in the metric; and that the coordinates adequately span all the spacetime region of interest.

It is often not possible to satisfy all these conditions, which is why a variety of coordinate choices are often made.